# How to make code repeat for a not predefined amount of times

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

As a project for school I have a touch sensor as an on/off switch connected to an arduino.When touched once it starts the motors, the servo and the ultrasonic sensor that are connected.Then when the sensor is touched again they all stop.My problem is that i cant make to servo and the ultrasonic repeatthe process of turning and calculating the distance more then once and i can't use loop since i can't know for how long will the circuit be running and if i do after the button is pressed for the seccond time i will have to wait for the amount of loops i have inserted to end before everything also stops.

Here is the code so far:

```
 #include <Servo.h>
    Servo servo; 
    int pos = 0;
    const int trigPin = 4;
    const int echoPin = 5; 
    long duration;
    int distance; 


    #define TouchSensor 13 
    int relay = 2; 
     // motor one
    int enA = 10;
    int in1 = 6;
    int in2 = 7;
    // motor two
    int enB = 5;
    int in3 = 8;
    int in4 = 9;

    boolean currentState = LOW;
    boolean lastState = LOW;
    boolean RelayState = LOW;

    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);  
      pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);  
      pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(TouchSensor, INPUT);
      servo.attach(3);
      pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); 
      pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
    }

    void loop() {
      currentState = digitalRead(TouchSensor);
        if (currentState == HIGH && lastState == LOW){
        Serial.println("pressed");
        digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);  
        digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(in4, LOW);

        servo.write(40);
     digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    distance= duration*0.034/2;
    Serial.print("Distance: ");
    Serial.println(distance);
     delay(500);
     servo.write(80);
     digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    distance= duration*0.034/2;
    Serial.print("Distance: ");
    Serial.println(distance);
     delay(500);
     servo.write(120);
     digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    distance= duration*0.034/2;
    Serial.print("Distance: ");
    Serial.println(distance);
     delay(500);
     servo.write(160);
     digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    distance= duration*0.034/2;
    Serial.print("Distance: ");
    Serial.println(distance);
    delay(500);

      delay(1);

        if (RelayState == HIGH){
          digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
          RelayState = LOW;
        digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(in2, LOW);  
        digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
        digitalWrite(in4, LOW); 
        } else {
          digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
          RelayState = HIGH;
        }
      }
      lastState = currentState;
    }
```

Thanks in advance. Sorry for any mistakes, english is not my first language.

Comment: Pick a random software library. If you examine its code, you will find plenty of loops whose number of iterations isn't known in advance. That's not how loops work. There is no law that says that all loops must iterate a fixed number of times. That's why the C++ language has keywords like `break` and `if`. You simply have to figure out the logic that's necessary to keep your loop running, and then stop it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, as in most other languages, it is possible to early-out from a loop using a `break` statement, so you can do something like this:

```
// A loop condition that will never terminate on its own
while(true)
{
  // Exit the loop when the sensor is triggered again
  if (sensorPressed()) {
    break;
  }

  // Otherwise, continue doing whatever is needed
}

// After the break, execution will resume here
```

Note that you will probably also want another loop to ensure that the sensor is not still reading as triggered before you enter the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

You really should consider making your code little bit easier to read. It was quite hard to follow along. Even its not code writing service I feel like have to make it more readable as a example. Functionality should be same excluding added loop for that state. ofc I cant try it out here. This is not perfect but I used already a while rewriting this so yeah hopefully you get something out of it. cheers.

```
#include <Servo.h>


/*
   Here I have added couple of definitions,
   like max servo position and speed of sound.
   Good rule is to name definitions in capital letters.
 */

#define TOUCHSENSOR 13
#define STEPSIZE 40
#define SPEED_OF_SOUND 0.034
#define MAX_SERVO_POS 160
const int trigPin = 4;
const int echoPin = 5;

int relay = 2;

/*
   its good to name variables so they indicate usage if possible,
   Here I have renamed motor PIN variables and enable pins.
   Not only for others but you will also eventually forget.
 */
int enableMotorOne = 10;
int motorOneTerminalOne = 6;
int motorOneTerminalTwo = 7;
// motor two
int enableMotorTwo = 5;
int motorTwoTerminalOne = 8;
int motorTwoTerminalTwo = 9;

boolean currentState = LOW;
boolean lastState = LOW;
boolean relayState = LOW;

Servo servo;

void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);
        pinMode(enableMotorOne, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(motorOneTerminalOne, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(motorOneTerminalTwo, OUTPUT);

        pinMode(enableMotorTwo, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(motorTwoTerminalOne, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(motorTwoTerminalTwo, OUTPUT);

        pinMode(TOUCHSENSOR, INPUT);
        servo.attach(3);
        pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}


void getDistance()
{
        /*
           Whole function for getting distance from ultrasonic sensor is moved Here
           usage in older implementation was repetitive and unnecessary
         */

        long duration;
        int distance;

        digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(2);
        digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(10);
        digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

        duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
        distance= duration*(SPEED_OF_SOUND/2);
        Serial.print("Distance: ");
        Serial.println(distance);
}

void scanState()
{
        Serial.println("pressed");
        digitalWrite(motorOneTerminalOne, LOW);
        digitalWrite(motorOneTerminalTwo, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(motorTwoTerminalOne, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(motorTwoTerminalTwo, LOW);

        while(currentState == HIGH && lastState == LOW)
        {
                /*
                   I think this is what you were asking, to loop this functionality
                   until state pins change state.
                 */

                for (size_t servoPos = 40; servoPos <= MAX_SERVO_POS; servoPos+=STEPSIZE) {
                        /*
                           This code in for loop here should do kinda 
                           same as you old code rows 
                           48-91. Please get familiar.
                         */
                        servo.write(servoPos);
                        getDistance();
                        delay(500);
                }

                if (relayState == HIGH) {
                        digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
                        relayState = LOW;
                        digitalWrite(motorOneTerminalOne, LOW);
                        digitalWrite(motorOneTerminalTwo, LOW);
                        digitalWrite(motorTwoTerminalOne, LOW);
                        digitalWrite(motorTwoTerminalTwo, LOW);
                } else {
                        digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
                        relayState = HIGH;
                }
        }
        delay(1);
}

void loop() {

        /*
           This is your new loop function, much easier to understand what is
           going on..
         */
        currentState = digitalRead(TOUCHSENSOR);
        if (currentState == HIGH && lastState == LOW) {
                scanState();
        }
        lastState = currentState;
}
```

Comment: Didn't want compress digitalWrites and other GPIO related stuff to one liners by using register manipulation. I guess that is too complicated at the moment. But consider reading about manipulating ports directly via their register values. You get less repeating code.